# PHP "The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable"

Tags: php, file, directory, file-upload, writable

When I try to upload a file on my localhost version of the website it gives me the following message:
"The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable"

The upload functionality is working perfectly on production server.

I checked the permissions of the destination folder about million times still getting the error also tried changing httpd and destination folder user/group with no luck.

The "is_writable" PHP function is returning false.... what am I missing ?

I am using fedora 13, Apache 2.2.15 and PHP 5.3.2

Thanks for your help

Wa'el

Comment: Can you show the full path to the destination folder? Can you show the permissions? Can you make 100% sure you have the correct user using `posix_getuid()`? Is safe mode active?

Comment: What user is the apache server running as?  It certainly sounds like this user does not have write access to the directory in question.

Comment: Did you try setting the permissions to 777?

Comment: Re: evil3 - DON'T DO THIS IN PRODUCTION - EVER.  Since this question specified localhost, maybe that's a valid troubleshooting step, but NEVER do this on a system that anyone else would be able to access in any way.

Comment: As you're on Fedora 13 and possibly have a default install: You're most likely running under Security-Enhanced Linux (SELinux), which denies writing to arbitrary directories. Did you check /var/log/audit/audit.log for denials? (In any case, please do NOT set permissions to 777. Making your data world-writable is never ever a good idea.)

Comment: Thanks Jonas, It turns out the SELinux was denying httpd to access the folder, thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Jonas: Wish you had made that an Answer rather than a comment - Would have upvoted for certain.

Comment: Jonas: thank a lot. solved my problem. i also, as Lucanos, wished you made this comment an answer so we could upvote it...
anyhow. thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are writing something your linux exec command then you have to turn PHP_Safe_MOD OFF in your setting. some times we use exec() command to perform operation. Just give it try. hope it would work.

Other thing you can do is try to change the permission Recursively 777 on the parent directory.

/a/b/c

chmod -R 777 a

Comment: Just a small observation/point - changing the permissions is a good suggestion, but I would not do so on the "parent directory". Permissions are best set as being the most restrictive whilst still allowing the system to operate - so I would make sure to change the permissions, recursively, on the Uploading Folder/Image Folder ONLY. I may simply be misreading your suggestion - just adding for clarity.

Comment: chmod 777 is *never* a "solution" to permission problems. It's more like "I'll leave my front door wide open in case I forget my keys some day". Do not do this, in any case. chmod 777 for a whole directory tree is even worse.

Comment: Thats correct, suggestion to change it to 777 is just to do quick test if it works then its permission problem, and he can use appropriate permission setting to make it work.